# Apply method in R missing argument (missing argument error)

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I am trying to use the apply method in R. But I keep getting the error: Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : missing argument in "b".

The code which produces the error:

```
my_data <- data.frame(x1 = 1:5, x2 = 2:6, x3 = 3)

myFunction <- function(a, b, c){
  return(a + b + c)
}

results = apply(my_data, 1, myFunction) #this line is producing the error massage
```

If I change "myFunction" to "sum" for example. Then there is no error. How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the function should be changed to

```
myFunction <- function(x) sum(x)
apply(my_data, 1, myFunction)
#[1]  6  8 10 12 14
```

Also, the sum operation by row is more efficient with `rowSums`

```
rowSums(my_data)
```

or specify the arguments separately by using a lambda/anonymous function in the OP's original function

```
apply(my_data, 1, function(x) myFunction(x[1], x[2], x[3]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mapply`:

```
with(my_data, mapply(myFunction, x1, x2, x3))
```

Comment: You could use `do.call(mapply, c(FUN = myFunction, unname(my_data)))`

Answer (score 1):

Also note your data.frame is a list of 3 vectors. You can add vectors just like a scalar.

```
with(my_data, x1 + x2 + x3)
```